# OwinContext.Request multi-part/form-data parsing?

Tags: forms, owin, multipartform-data

Is there an easy way to parse *multi-part/form-data* information from an  **OwinContext.Request** instance?

I know how to do this using **HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get()**, but I'm not sure if I really want to be doing that in the Owin pipeline.

I know I can use **.ReadFormAsync()** to get an **IFormCollection**, which appears to work fine for standard submits, but with a *multi-part/form-data* post the boundary value, content type, and variable name are all getting rolled into the key. So I can't just do **formVars.Get("VariableName")**, because it's not the variable name, it's a composite. Seems like it shouldn't be doing that though... right?

```
public AppFunc PreAuthMiddleware(AppFunc next) {
  AppFunc appFunc = async (IDictionary<string, object> environment) => {
    IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
    IFormCollection formVars = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();

    ... Now What ...

    await next.Invoke(environment);
  };
  return appFunc;
}
```

I was hoping that accessing form variables and file data would be as easy as it was with **HttpContext**, but it seems there may be more work to be done.

If anyone has any insight on this, please let me know. Otherwise I'll probably just end up hacking the key names together if I see the main content-type is *multi-part/form-data*.